# PDO query not working after SQL Server Function Modify

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo

I updated a SQL Server function (scalar valued if it matters). The function works exactly as intended when I execute it in SQL Server Management Studios. However ever since the modification the Ubuntu Server I run some web forms on no longer resolve queries that reference this function.

What happened? I have restarted both the SQL Server and the Ubuntu Server and the issue persists.

Comment: *"However ever since the modification the Ubuntu Server I run some web forms on no longer resolve queries that reference this function."* What does this mean? Are they failing? What is the error?

Comment: The query just fails. I am not getting a response on why it doesn't resolve but the only change was that this sql server function was modified.